# Checking of map.getFeatureLayer in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

How can I determine whether map.getFeatureLayer correctly retrieves a FeatureLayer for a given Google ID, and if the FeatureLayer is present, how do I check if it represents a location with polygon boundaries on the map?

Ive added 2 examples - in first everithing is OK, but in second - no LOCALITY coverage for Spain, so how can I check if getFeatureLayer returned null?

https://jsfiddle.net/andrewzheludkov2/3zy92gqf/12/

https://jsfiddle.net/andrewzheludkov2/0bozhfuk/5/

Tries this approach

```
featureLayerTest = map.getFeatureLayer("ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1");
if (featureLayerTest) {
    console.log("FeatureLayer is present:", featureLayerTest);
} else {
    console.log("FeatureLayer is not present for the given Google ID");
}
```

But both valid and invalid featureLayerTest return some object (FeatureLayer is present:
Object { Ig: {…}, featureType_: "ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1", Jg: null, Mg: null, Kg: true, Ng: undefined, … })

No info in google tutorials(

Comment: There is the `isAvailable` property but it is `true` for both. I don't think there is a way.  Polygon boundaries was a (very) long awaited feature but unfortunately Google came up with a very restricted product that lacks a lot of features. I can only suggest that you open a new feature request in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853) (and link it here).

Comment: isAvailable detects if the feature is abailable 'in general', if it is turned on in console. Thanks.